# Insert hyperlink and remove hyperlink in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create 2 simple button look like:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IAlZ.png]

For insert and remove hyperlink to my HTML in textarea.

My code is:

```
function formatDoc(sCmd, sValue) {  
  oDoc = document.getElementById("textBox");
  document.execCommand(sCmd, false, sValue); oDoc.focus(); 
}
```

and on body :

```
<div><img class="intLink" title="Hyperlink" onclick="var sLnk=prompt('Inserire lURL','http://');if(sLnk&&sLnk!=''&&sLnk!='http://'){formatDoc('createlink',sLnk)}" src="link.gif" /></div>
<textarea id="textBox"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></textarea>
```

But that can't create and add Hyperlink to my element.
What is wrong?

ps: is there simple way to remove link from element?

Answer (score 0):

You can not put hyperlinks in textarea nor html. It is ignored.

you can use this to convert to hyperlinks and show it in div

```
function ConvertToLinks() {
  str = document.getElementById("S1").value;
  str = str.replace(/\r\n|\n/g,'<br>');
  document.getElementById('txtLinks').innerHTML = str;
}

<textarea rows="5" id="S1" name="S1" cols="40">
  <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
  <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>

  <a href="http://webdeveloper.com">Web Developer</a>

 </textarea>
 <br><button onclick="ConvertToLinks()">Convert to Links</button>
 <div id="txtLinks" style="width:350px;min-height:100px;border:1px solid red"></div>
```